# Cannot access Accessibility domain in chrome dev tools protocol

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, accessibility, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to access the Accessibility domain of the dev tools protocol without success.
I'm getting:
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: {"code":-32601,"message":"'Accessibility.getFullAXTree' wasn't found"}`

I'm able to access other experimental APIs for example `Emulation.setFocusEmulationEnabled`

Here is my code:

```
chrome.debugger.attach({tabId: customerTabId} , '1.3', () => {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
        {tabId: customerTabId},
        'Accessibility.getFullAXTree',                      
        (result) => {
            console.log(result);        
        }
    );
});
```

Did anyone try to access the accessibility domain with success?

Comment: Judging by the source code you need to send `Accessibility.enable` first, just like in many/most other CDP domains. Otherwise it may be a bug in Chrome. See if changing options in `chrome://accessibility` helps.

Comment: Seems that Accessibility.enable is not found as well

Comment: wOxxOm do you know a google group / github repo where I can report this issue?

Comment: FWIW it works for me here in Windows 10 + Chrome 115, no need for Accessibility.enable.

Comment: I just upgraded chrome from 110 to 115 and it seems to work as well!
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attach')
    at <anonymous>:1:17

I get this error when I try to run above command in the console, any idea? @BenBracha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to wOxxOm help, upgrading chrome from 110 to 115 seems to solve this issue.